Why we need date tiered compaction and how it is different from size tiered compaction
In size tiered compaction if time series data comes in then each similar sized sstables must be close in time and hence it should work like date tiered compaction right?
Example
Let's consider a practical example where Size-Tiered Compaction (STC) does not work well for time-series data. Suppose you have an application that collects temperature sensor readings every minute. This data is inserted into a Cassandra database, and over time, SSTables are created based on the incoming write load.
Example Scenario
Data Ingestion
Day 1: Data is continuously written every minute, resulting in small SSTables being created throughout the day.
Day 2: Data continues to be written every minute, leading to more small SSTables.
Day 3: Data continues in the same pattern.

Let's visualize this with SSTables created over three days:
Day 1 SSTables: SSTable_1_1, SSTable_1_2, SSTable_1_3, ..., SSTable_1_N
Day 2 SSTables: SSTable_2_1, SSTable_2_2, SSTable_2_3, ..., SSTable_2_N
Day 3 SSTables: SSTable_3_1, SSTable_3_2, SSTable_3_3, ..., SSTable_3_N

Size-Tiered Compaction Process
Initial State: On Day 1, the system starts with several small SSTables (e.g., SSTable_1_1 to SSTable_1_10).
First Compaction: As the size of SSTables reaches a certain threshold, STC compacts some of these SSTables into a larger SSTable (e.g., SSTable_1_A, which contains data from SSTable_1_1 to SSTable_1_5).
Subsequent Compactions: On Day 2, more small SSTables are created and eventually compacted (e.g., SSTable_2_A, which contains data from SSTable_2_1 to SSTable_2_5).

Here all the compacted sstables have continuous time series data right so it is similar to date tiered compaction right?
Please explain me why I'm wrong with an example for me to understand
